# R+Shiny+leaflet: aggregate values on map according to zoom level

Tags: r, shiny, maps, r-leaflet

Please consider the small example at the end of the post.
I simply put a lot of markers on a geographical map.
I would like to be able to do two things:

1. associate a value (simply a number) to each marker on the map. The number should be visible when I hover over the marker with the mouse.
2. To keep it simple, let us say we associate the value 1 to each marker. It would be nice if, according to the zoom level, the total number (sum of the individual values attached to the markers) was aggregated suitably. For instance, when I zoom out I should see a single marker with value 40 and then progressively more markers with an associated value and the sum of those values will always be 40.

Does anybody know how to achieve that?
Thanks!

Thanks!

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
        options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591613/changing-marker-clustering-by-zoom-level-in-shiny-leaflet-r

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the aggregation yourself and then add it with different group ids. Yo can then handle which group is displayed at which zoomlevel over `groupOptions`. For more iformation you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503281/display-layers-at-certain-zoom-levels-in-r-leaflet)

Comment: I will have a look.